# Check Radio Input From Click on Parent (jquery/DOM)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, radio-button, jquery-selectors

I need to check a radio button when the user clicks anywhere in the parent li. The ul is in the original html but the li and radio button are rendered to the DOM in a for loop inside a function below (displaySearchResults(responseJson).

Have not been able to apply any change to the radio button for the specific clicked li (sometimes able to change all radio buttons) -- no luck using the this keyword or various class/id/element combinations to target children of the clicked li.

Here is the event listener followed by relevant code.

This has been an absolute nightmare, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

***EVENT LISTENER***

```
function select(){
$('.results-list-item').click(event => { 
let name = $(this)
console.log('li click')
//various attempts at marking the child radio button as checked 
//$(this).closest($('input')).prop("checked", true)
//$(this).children($('input')).attr('checked','true')
$('.results-list-item').children($('input.radio')).attr('checked','')
 }) 
};
```

***DISPLAY***

```
function displaySearchResults(responseJson) { 
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      $('#results-list').append(
      `
      <li class='results-list-item'>
      <h3>${results[i].name}</h3> 
      <input type='radio' id='${results[i].name}' value='${responseJson.results[i].id}' required>
     </li> 
     `
      )
    }
  select()
}
```

***HTML***

```
<main class='container'>
<section id='results'>
<form id='js-results-form'>
<ul id='results-list'>
</ul>
<input type='submit' value='Select Game'></input>
</form>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! switching to .on() solved this problem. It was previously solved on stack overflow but I just didn't realize how to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;Dr:**:

1. You don't need any JS click listener, simply use a `<label>` as wrapper.
2. PS: `$collection.click()` will work only for already present (on DOM ready) Elements. Your elements are generated dynamically: therefore use the **[.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)** Method: `$staticParent.on("eventName", "dynamicChild", fn)`

---

**Ok;Wr:**:

1. Remove totally your `functionSelect()`
2. Instead use the jQuery `.on()` method with [delegated event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) in order to assigning a listener to the static parent element for an event that was triggered from a specific present **or future** element target.
3. Use `ev.preventDefault();` inside the handler to prevent the label or checkbox/ or radio firing back
4. What to make your LI clickable?? You don't have to, simply use the HTML `<label>` element and set it in CSS as `display: block;`

```js
// How it works:
// "Static parent" on "evtName"  "dynamic child"    
$('#results-list').on("click", ".results-list-item", function(ev) {
  console.log(this);               // The LI Element
  console.log(ev.currentTarget);   // The LI element
  console.log(ev.delegateTarget);  // The static UL Element  
  console.log(ev.target);          // Some Element dispatcher, who knows...
});
```

Further more, for displaying the LIs results:

```js
// Elements

const $resultsList = $('#results-list');

// Templates

const tpl_item = (item) => `<li class='results-list-item'>
  <label>
    <span>${item.name}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="${item.name}" value="${item.id}" required>
  </label>
</li>`;

// UI

const UI_displaySearchResults = (responseJson) => {
  const html_listItems = responseJson.reduce((s, item) => s + tpl_item(item), "");
  $resultsList.append(html_listItems);
};

// Events

$resultsList.on("click", "li", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent label (input) firing twice
  console.log(this.textContent.trim()); // The LI element content, if needed?
});

// Finally: on Init or on AJAX request, does not matters any more:

UI_displaySearchResults([
  {id: 4, name: "Lorem ipsum"},
  {id: 9, name: "Dolor dolor, dolor"},
  {id: 8, name: "Sit amet"},
]);
```

```css
#results-list label {
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  background: gold; /* demo only */
}
```

```html
<ul id="results-list"></ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I take a look on your problem and maybe you could solve it just with HTML, assuming that the input will have a text on it you could add a  tag and using a prop "for" to link the text to the input

I also took the opportunity to correct a detail that you ended up missing, when you are calling `${results[i].name}` the responseJson is missing
Like the following example:

```
$('#results-list').append(
    `
    <li class='results-list-item'>
        <h3>${responseJson.results[i].name}</h3> 
        <label for='${responseJson.results[i].id}'>
            <input type='radio' id='${responseJson.results[i].id}' value='${responseJson.results[i].name}' required>
            ${responseJson.results[i].name}
        </label>
    </li>
    `
)
```

I hope have helped!